# C# .wav file processing advice needed

Tags: c#, naudio

What I am making is a small audio editor that loads a .wav file and displays it in the time domain. The user can select a part of it and zoom in or DFT the chunk which displays a small window in the frequency domain. (extra functionality to be added later)

**I think I am making a mistake when splitting my byte array into two float arrays.**

I use NAudio to get my samples into a byte array.
Then I use a loop I found on stack overflow to split the array into left and right channels.

```
private void readToArrays(WaveFileReader pcm) {

        wf = pcm.WaveFormat;

        int samplesDesired = (int)pcm.Length;

        buffer = new byte[samplesDesired * 4];
        left = new float[samplesDesired];
        right = new float[samplesDesired];

        int bytesRead = pcm.Read(buffer, 0, samplesDesired);

        if (wf.BitsPerSample == 16) {

            if (wf.Channels == 1) {
                for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length / 4; i++)
                    //handle
            }
            else if (wf.Channels == 2) {
                int index = 0;
                for (int sample = 0; sample < bytesRead / 4; sample++) {
                    left[sample] = BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer, index);
                    index += 2;
                    right[sample] = BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer, index);
                    index += 2;
                }                     
            }
        }else if (wf.BitsPerSample == 8) {
            if (wf.Channels == 1) {
               //handle
            }
            else if (wf.Channels == 2) {
               //handle
            }
        }
    }
```

TL:DR: *I get a lot of noise from playback with individual files. What I need is some advice as to how I can still be able to modify my samples / DFT them AND be able to output them without noise. Do note that I am just a 2nd year Computing student and do not have years of experience.*

Extra Info : Bit Depth = 16; Sample Rate = 22050;